# How to terminate sequence of switch maps in RxJava2 on error

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I am trying to implement a refresh token flow in RxJava2 and Kotlin and I have trouble handling errors. There are several requests that need to be done in sequence but the sequence differs in case there are some errors.

Basically, if I try to use my refresh token and receive `400 - Bad Request`response because the token is not valid, I need to terminate the flow and do not execute the next `switchMap` (and ideally, I would like to return the final `Observable<ApplicationRoot>`). But I am not sure how to achieve this.

If I use `onErrorReturn`, I will just pass the returned result to the next switch map. And `doOnError` just executes the step when the request fails but the whole sequence continues.

```
fun refreshToken(): Observable<ApplicationRoot> {
        // try to use the refresh token to obtain an access token
        return authRepository.refreshToken(token)
                .switchMap { response ->
                    // process response here
                    userRepository.getUser() // fetch user details
                }.doOnError {
                    // TODO - return final result, do not jump to next switchMap

                    // refresh token is not valid -> go to login screen
                    Observable.just(ApplicationRoot.LOGIN) // not working
                }.switchMap { response -> // excpects response of type UserResponse
                    // save user details here
                }
}
```

Does anyone know who to jump out of the sequence of switch maps if some error occurs?

Comment: Have you looked at `onErrorResumeNext(Function)` for handling the error and `flatMap` to decide how to continue after an upstream item?

Comment: I was trying to but it does not make much sense to me. Could you provide an example?

Comment: What is type of `response` lambda parameter in first `switchMap`?

Comment: @Google It is my custom `TokenResponse` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you should do something like this:

```
fun refreshToken(): Observable<ApplicationRoot> {
    return authRepository.refreshToken(token)
            .switchMap { response ->
                userRepository.getUser()
            }
            .switchMap { response -> // do something with user response
            }
            .map { ApplicationRoot.ROOT_THAT_MEANS_SUCCESS }
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.just(ApplicationRoot.LOGIN))
}
```

I am not aware about implementation of `authRepository.refreshToken` and how do `responses` look like, but in case if `response` is your custom object rather than `retrofit2.Response<T>` it should work.